# not able to refresh datagrid from ModernDialog in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to refresh datagrid which is updated by updating data. but i am not able to see result. i have called filldatagrid method from update button but still i am not able to see changes in home page.

**Home.xaml**

```
        <DataGrid Margin="10,40,10,10" Name="grdEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Update">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Click="Button_Click"  Tag="{Binding Id}"  Content="Update"  
                                    Padding="0,0,0,10"/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Check"  IsThreeState="True" Binding="{Binding Id}" />

        </DataGrid.Columns>


    </DataGrid>
```

**Home.Xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Home : UserControl
{
  EmployeeContexts em = new EmployeeContexts();



    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



    FillDataGrid(); 
    }

    public void FillDataGrid()
    {

        var emp = em.swap.ToList();

        this.DataContext = emp.AsEnumerable();

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        var code = button.Tag;
        if (code != null)
        {
            var mem = em.swap.Find(code);

            ModernDialog1 md = new ModernDialog1();
            md.name.Text = mem.Name;
            md.address.Text = mem.Addressa;
            md.city.Text = mem.City;
            md.hide.Text = (mem.Id).ToString();

            md.Show();
        }
        else
        {

            ModernDialog.ShowMessage("Wrong:Input", "MY App", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK);

        }
    }




}
```

**ModernDialog1.xaml**

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label FontSize="20">Name</Label>
    <TextBox Name="name" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,11,15"></TextBox>
    <Label FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1">Address</Label>
    <TextBox Name="address" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,11,15"></TextBox>
    <Label FontSize="20" Grid.Row="2">City</Label>
    <TextBox Name="city" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10,10,11,15"></TextBox>
    <Button Foreground="Blue" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,26,10">Update</Button>
    <Button Foreground="Red" Click="Button1_Click" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="25,10,44,10">Close</Button>
    <TextBlock Name="hide" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Grid>
```

**ModernDialog1.xaml.cs**

public partial class ModernDialog1 : ModernDialog

```
{
    EmployeeContexts em = new EmployeeContexts();

    public ModernDialog1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


       this.Buttons = new Button[] { null };

    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        testofpage testofpage=new testofpage();
        testofpage.Id = int.Parse(hide.Text);
        testofpage.Name = name.Text;
        testofpage.City = city.Text;
        testofpage.Addressa = address.Text;
        em.Entry(testofpage).State = EntityState.Modified;
        em.SaveChanges();


        Home hm = new Home();
        hm.FillDataGrid();

        this.Hide();

    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            this.Hide();
    }
}
```

**testofpage.cs**

public class testofpage : INotifyPropertyChanged

```
{
    public int Id { get; set; }



    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}n{1}n{2}", Name, Addressa, City);
    }
    private string name,address,city;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set
        {
            if (this.name != value)
            {
                this.name = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    public string Addressa
    {
        get { return this.address; }
        set
        {
            if (this.address != value)
            {
                this.address = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Addressa");
            }
        }
    }
    public string City
    {
        get { return this.city; }
        set
        {
            if (this.city != value)
            {
                this.city = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("City");
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

}
```